# Blend 4 not liking 64 bit dlls?

Tags: expression-blend-4

I set my project to x64 inside visual studio, when I switch to Blend and try to add an object datasource, my assembly does not appear unless I switch it back to x86.  Does Blend not support 64bit dlls?

Edit:
Yes I did check the "show all assemblies" checkbox.